# Configuration tmuxinator

Tags: tmux

I am a user of zsh and tmux. I discovered tmuxinator for configuration scripts to manage sessions, and it's awesome. But I have a problem on a machine, Here is my yaml file tmuxinator:

```
name: admin
root: ~/
tmux_options: -v -2 # Pass arguments to tmux
windows:
  - mail:
    panes:
      - mutt
      - #empty, will just run plain bash
  - shell: ls
```

Then the [generated script](https://gist.github.com/hobbestigrou/82c0cd78282d7bd4cdf2). I don't know why.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It was a version problem. By installing the latest version that works.